# Component visiblity getting delay while drop the component in the panel in java swing

Tags: java, swing

In my project I have used drag and drop functionality to drop the Icon from 1st panel to 2nd panel. The 1st panel contains three buttons with different icons and the 2nd panel is added as the destination (Drop place) in the desktop pane. While drag and drop I have used a panel and label to place the icon in the 2nd panel. The icon which is available in the label visibility getting delay(nearly 5 - 10 sec) at the first time drag and drop. After that there is no time delay for the drag and drop. This happens all the time while start my project. I have tried repaint() and revalidate() for all the panels still the delay is there. Kindly suggest any idea to reduce the delay.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: *"Kindly suggest any idea to reduce the delay"* - A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)